# QAbstractListModel delegating in MapIteMVieW

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm using `QAbstractListModel` to build some MapQuickItems on a map, but I am having trouble accessing the data in the model. 
The Model header is as:

```
class AdventureOnMap
{
public:
AdventureOnMap(const int &adventureId, const int &tagId, const QString &name, const QString &desc, const QString &clue, const int &award, const double &geoLat, const double &geoLong);

int     adventureId() const;
int     tagId() const;
QString name() const;
QString desc() const;
QString clue() const;
int     award() const;
double  geoLat() const;
double geoLong() const;

private:
int     l_adventureId;
int     l_tagId;
QString l_name;
QString l_desc;
QString l_clue;
int     l_award;
double  l_geoLat;
double  l_geoLong;
};

class AdventureOnMapModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
enum AdventureOnMapRoles {
    AdventureIdRole  = Qt::UserRole + 1,
    TagIdRole,
    NameRole,
    DescRole,
    ClueRole,
    AwardRole,
    GeoLatRole,
    GeoLongRole
};

AdventureOnMapModel(QObject *parent = 0);

void addAdventureOnMap(const AdventureOnMap &AdventureOnMap);

int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;

QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

protected:
QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
private:
QList<AdventureOnMap> l_adventuresOnMap;
};
```

I'm accessing the model through a `Q_INVOKABLE` that returns a pointer to this model, as:

`Q_INVOKABLE AdventureOnMapModel* buildAdventuresOnMap() const;`

And I call it in QML as:

```
MapItemView {
    model: thisAdvendture.buildAdventuresOnMap()
//this returns AdventureOnMapModel*
    delegate: MapQuickItem {
        coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(geoLat,geoLong)
        //Anhors pointer right in the middle of bottom
        anchorPoint.x: image.width * 0.5
        anchorPoint.y: image.height

        sourceItem: Column {
            Image { id: image; source: "../Resources/marker.png" }
            Text { text: name;
                    font.bold: true
            }
```

But the model seems to be empty(although I see it being filled in `qDebug()` output) or doesn't delegate, and I can't find the reason why. Am I accessing the data in the model wrong? am I delegating it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete code, you need to post .cpp file also. But I will take a guess, I think you have not implemented the rowCount and data functions correctly - they should use the l_adventuresOnMap member variable to return the correct data for both those functions.